# Android setting background image - poor performance

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, imagebutton

I am having problem with bad performance when setting the background image of image button.

## First way

In this way the rendering performance is excellent:

```
holder.buttonSound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aaaa_1);
```

## Second way

But if i choose the second way like below, the performance is poor:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(sound.getPath(), "mipmap", context.getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id);
holder.buttonSound.setBackground(drawable);
```

I want use the second way, but how i can gain a better performance.

Comment: Why do you want to use the second way?

Comment: Because its more comfortable for me ;) Is it possible to get the same performance as in the first way ?

Comment: Well, you can look to the setBackgroundResource implementation. One way to improve the performance of your code is to load the Drawable outside the main thread.